# CakePHP / PHP, Croatian date convert to mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date, cakephp

We need from the html form send a date in the "Croatian" format **29. 01. 2015** (pay attention to the space after the dot), but before we save the date in the database it is necessary to convert the string in mysql date format **2015-01-29**.

We are using CakePHP 2.6 framework, so you can combine CakeTime helper and plain PHP.

Currently we use this function:

```
// $pickerDate = '29. 01. 2015';
public function pickerDateToMysql($pickerDate){
    $datetime = explode(' ', str_replace('.','',$pickerDate));
    $date = implode('-',array_reverse($datetime));
    debug($date);
    return $date;  // 2015-01-29
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` method to rearrange date format

```
public function pickerDateToMysql($pickerDate){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $pickerDate);
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}  
$CroatianDate = '29. 01. 2015';
pickerDateToMysql($CroatianDate);
```

Comment: Only a small correction **m**. instead of **M.** $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d. m. Y', $pickerDate);

Comment: was type issue.. thx